# Call class generated at runtime from another object generated at runtime

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, runtime, codedom

I'm working on a C# project whereby I'm dynamically building the mapping for an ORM solution, namely [nHibernate](http://nhibernate.info/), at runtime from a given database on a given server. Right now, I'm focusing on getting the basic object and relational-mapping class runtime generation working. I'm able to compile in-memory at runtime the following class via CodeDOM:

```
namespace DataDictionary.Domain
{
    public class Entity
    {
        public virtual int EntityID { get; set; }
        public virtual string EntityName { get; set; }
        public virtual DateTime EntityFoundationDate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

However, when I try to compile the equivalent of the following class using CodeDOM:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using NHibernate.Cfg;
using NHibernate.Cfg.MappingSchema;
...
namespace DataDictionary.Domain
{
    public class EntityMap : ClassMapping<Entity>
    {
        public EntityMap()
        {
            this.Table(Entity);
            this.ID(p => p.EntityID);
            this.Property(p => p.EntityName);
            this.Property(p => p.EntityFoundationDate);
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following error when compiling: `error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Entity' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

My question is *why* `Entity`, despite having been placed in the correct namespace at runtime compilation, is not being seen by `EntityMap`.

Also, for reference, here's the method I use to create `EntityMap`:

```
    public static object CreateNewObject(ref object table, AssemblyName domain, params FieldInfo[] columns)
    {
        if (columns == null || columns.Length == 0)
            return null;

        string tableName = table.GetType().Name;

        //check to see if a class exists which both matches the name of `table`
        //and whose full name contains the correct assembly to be used.
        var namespaceCheck = (from assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                              from type in assembly.GetTypes()
                              where type.Name == tableName && Utilities.GetFriendlyAssemblyName(type.FullName).Equals("DataDictionary.Domain")
                              select type).FirstOrDefault();

        if (namespaceCheck == null) 
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Valid type not found.");

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("using NHibernate; using NHibernate.Cfg; using NHibernate.Cfg.MappingSchema; using NHibernate.Dialect; using NHibernate.Mapping.ByCode; using NHibernate.Mapping.ByCode.Conformist; ");

        builder.Append("namespace DataDictionary.Domain{");

        builder.AppendFormat("public class {0}Map : ClassMapping<{0}> {{", tableName);
        builder.AppendFormat("public {0}Map(){{\n",tableName);
        builder.AppendFormat("this.Table({0});", tableName);

        //find the ID column.
        var list = columns.Where(x => x.Name.ToUpper().Contains("ID"));
        builder.AppendFormat("this.ID(p => p.{0})", Utilities.cleanFieldName(list.ElementAt(0).Name));
        columns = columns.Where(x => !x.Equals(list.ElementAt(0))).ToArray();

        //map the properties.
        foreach (FieldInfo column in columns)
        {
            builder.AppendFormat("this.Property(p => p.{0});", Utilities.cleanFieldName(column.Name));
        }

        //close all open brackets.
        builder.Append("}}}");

        //send code to helper class for runtime compilation via CodeDOM.
        return CodeDOM_Helpers.Execute(builder.ToString(), tableName,domain.Name);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you intend perhaps this:

```
   public EntityMap()
    {
        this.Table(Entity);
        this.ID(p => p.Entity);
        this.Property(p => p.EntityName);
        this.Property(p => p.EntityFoundationDate);
    }
```

to read as:

```
   public EntityMap()
    {
        this.Table(Entity);
        this.ID(p => p.EntityID);  // since the type of p does not have an "Entity" property
        this.Property(p => p.EntityName);
        this.Property(p => p.EntityFoundationDate);
    }
```

Comment: Also, would like to add that this did not solve my problem as I still get the same error. (Which makes sense as it was a typo within the mapping  class which would've triggered when the mapping class actually saw the object class.)